# POSTFIX-CYRUS SASL AUTHENTICATION

Tags: linux, email, google

I have a question regarding Postfix-SASL authentication. I have created a mail server with Postfix. I have a domain, a public IP, and an MX record pointing towards my IP. I can now send and receive email from my domain. Now I want to make it connect through a mail client.

I am using centos 7, quite new to this, so having some problems with it can anyone guide me through this? I have tried using cyrus but not working.

```
    yum install postfix -y
    yum -y install cyrus*
```

My `main.cf` file of Postfix looks like

```
    myhostname = mx12.example.com
    myorigin = $mydomain
    mydomain = example.com
    inet_interface = <my public ip>, localhost
    inet_protocol = all
    mydestination = localhost, $myhostname, $mydomain.....
    smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
    broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
    smtpd_sasl_type = cyrus
    smtpd_sasl_path = smtpd
    smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
    smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_unauth_destination
```

`/etc/sasl2/smtpd.conf`:

```
    pwcheck_method: saslauthd
    mech_list: plain login
    log_level: 7
```

`/etc/pam.d/smtp`:

```
    #%PAM-1.0
    auth       include      pam_unix.so
    account    include      pam_unix.so
```

`/etc/postfix/master.cf`:

```
    submission inet n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
      -o syslog_name=postfix/submission
      -o smtpd_tls_security_level=encrypt
      -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
      -o smtpd_reject_unlisted_recipient=no
    #  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=$mua_client_restrictions
    #  -o smtpd_helo_restrictions=$mua_helo_restrictions
    #  -o smtpd_sender_restrictions=$mua_sender_restrictions
      -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
      -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING
```

Commands:

```
    systemctl enable --now postfix
    systemctl enable --now saslauthd
    testsaslauthd -u user -p password -s smtp
```

The firewall has open ports -: 25/tcp 143/tcp 587/tcp

So these are my configuration files. Anyone have a solution?

Comment: Please edit your question and use the provided formatting options. Use the `{}` button to format config files and commands.

Comment: plz view and help me i have edited i have  to complete it by today
thank you

Comment: You may have postfix running, but now you need to attach an IMAP server to that.  `dovecot` is a good one.  I just went through this fantastic guide this week to get it all working: https://www.linuxbabe.com/mail-server/setup-basic-postfix-mail-sever-ubuntu.  It's specific to ubuntu, but it's recent so I bet the dovecot/postfix configurations aren't too different.